# Switch byobu session quickly?

Tags: byobu

There is <kbd>F6</kbd> for detach session. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> for detach session without logout. The main purpose when someone hits <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> is to either open an existing or start a new byobu session. That's at least very true in my daily use. So how can we set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> for switching session? That will save the user the effort of typing `byobu` to start it up again. The menu would just be like the one presented when user start `byobu` from terminal: multiple choices to start byobu.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @MichaelBay Dear my beloved director. I edited the post. Please take another look :)

Comment: LOL I'm just **a** Michael Bay, not **the** Michael Bay. We aren't related as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

Found it. 
Edit the file `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux` to change tmux prefix back to C-b because F12 does not work on my computer.

```
# set -g prefix F12
set -g prefix C-b
unbind-key -n C-a
```

Save the file and press `F5` to refresh byobu config. Then I can switch session like this (thanks to this [cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/andreyvit/2921703)):

```
C-b (          previous session
C-b )          next session
C-b L          ‘last’ (previously used) session
C-b s          choose a session from a list
```

This is the undocumented part of `byobu` but since it uses `tmux`, I could figure out many other advance uses of byobu :)